# Having issues trying to redirect file to stdin using dup2() and open() and execv()

Tags: c, fork, exec

Edit: The issue is that echo does not read from stdin apparently. Thanks @Jonathan Leffler

I have a programming exercise, and my code is below:

```
int processProgram(char **tokens, int requireWait) {
    char *cmd = tokens[0];
    if (access(cmd, R_OK) == -1) {
        printf("%s not found\n", cmd);
        return -1;
    }

    int index = 1;
    char *iterator = tokens[index];
    int inputTokenIndex = 0;
    // Look for a < to figure out where the redirection is
    while (iterator != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(iterator, "<") == 0) {                      // <---- THIS IS WHERE I ATTEMPT TO FIND THE INDEX OF "<"
            if (access(tokens[index + 1], R_OK) == -1) {
                printf("%s does not exist\n", tokens[index + 1]);
                return -1;
            }
            // set null at <
            tokens[index] = NULL;
            inputTokenIndex = index + 1;
            break;
        }
        index++;
        iterator = tokens[index];
    }
    // basically create a struct to store pids and stuff....
    processList *process = addNewProcess();
    int childPid = fork();
    if (childPid == 0) {
        // is the child
        if (inputTokenIndex > 0) {
            // if previously strcmp "<" is true
            // set redirection for input....
            int fd = open(tokens[inputTokenIndex], O_RDONLY);   // <----- THIS IS WHERE I DO THE REDIRECTING FOR STDIN!
            dup2(fd, STDIN_FILENO);
            close(fd);
        }
        // start from where inputTokenIndex could have left off
        // since > is always at least after < in our test cases
        index = inputTokenIndex + 1;
        iterator = tokens[index];
        while (iterator != NULL) {                            // <--- LOOKING FOR ">" and "2>", CURRENTLY THIS WORKS FINE
            // look for output redirection FROM previous while loop onwards
            int out = 0;
            if (strcmp(iterator, ">") == 0) {
                // stdout
                out = STDOUT_FILENO;
            } else if (strcmp(iterator, "2>") == 0) {
                // stderr
                out = STDERR_FILENO;
            }
            if (out != 0) {
                int fd = open(tokens[index + 1], O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT, 0777);
                dup2(fd, out);
                tokens[index] = NULL;
                close(fd);
            }
            index++;
            iterator = tokens[index];
        }
        
        int value = execv(cmd, tokens);                  // <----- EXEC IS HERE!!
        if (value == -1) {
            exit(errno);
        }
        exit(0);
    } else {
        int status;
        if (requireWait == 1) {
            // wait for process to finish
            process->pid = childPid;
            wait(&status);
            process->running = 0;
            process->status = status;
            if (status != 0) {
                printf("%s failed", cmd);
            }
        } else {
            process->pid = childPid;
            printf("Child[%d] in background\n", childPid);
            // no return should be expected
            status = 0;
        }
        return status;
    }
}
```

The idea is to simulate linux redirection using < and >

tokens is the array of strings provided into the shell.

Example call to write hello to "a.txt": /bin/echo hello > ./a.txt

**The problem**

It does not work for redirecting in, i.e "/bin/echo < ./a.txt" would echo as if there was no arguments passed in, which is an empty line. "/bin/sleep < ./a.txt" would say no arguments passed in when the file is not empty.

The file a.txt is created using this program. So full example would be

/bin/echo hellooooo > ./a.txt

/bin/echo < ./a.txt

in which the first command successfully creates and writes a.txt, but the second command produces only an empty line

**How can you help**

Assume that tokens is correct, and that the filename exists, why doesn't the execv() call take in input from the filename given that I redirected it????

Thank you for reading this!!

Comment: `echo` doesn't read standard input; you won't be able to tell if your redirection was successful.  Use another program — `cat`, for example — to test it.

Comment: Ok thank you, would never have figured that out myself...

Comment: Wouldn't you have figured it out if you tried it in a regular shell and saw that it didn't work there, either?

Comment: You never check the return value of `open`. A lot of readers here will just assume `open` failed, and claim that is your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I noted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69134160/having-issues-trying-to-redirect-file-to-stdin-using-dup2-and-open-and-execv#comment122189106_69134160), the `echo` command does not read standard input, so you won't be able to tell whether your input redirection was successful with `echo` (or with `sleep`).

Use a command which does read standard input — `cat` is the easiest example, but `tr` and `sed` could be sensible alternatives.